# Running multiple commands using one file

Tags: bash

I have a file with listed commands: first is the script name, like: get_1000g_r2_prevcf_snplist_e.pl and everything else is argument to the script. Here is a couple of lines in the major file which I am trying to use to run all these commands, say runscript:

```
get_1000g_r2_prevcf_snplist_e.pl 11:9554976-9657232 EUR ENSG00000133789.txt
get_1000g_r2_prevcf_snplist_e.pl 11:70272382-70444560 EUR ENSG00000131626.txt
get_1000g_r2_prevcf_snplist_e.pl 11:94324686-94541163 EUR ENSG00000020922.txt
...
```

I am doing:

```
chmod u+x runscript
sh runscript
```

I am getting:

```
line 1: get_1000g_r2_prevcf_snplist_e.pl: command not found
```

Why that would be? Everything is located in the current directory. There is no issue with paths.

I did do:

```
export PATH=$PATH:.
```

and after running:

```
get_1000g_r2_prevcf_snplist_e.pl 11:9554976-9657232 EUR ENSG00000133789.txt
```

I got:

```
-bash: ./get_1000g_r2_prevcf_snplist_e.pl: Permission denied
```

Comment: Programs are looked up in `PATH`, not the current directory.

Comment: The permission error is interesting. What are the permissions on that file? Is it executable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_1000g_r2_prevcf_snplist_e.pl` is a file name, not a command.

Your scripts are written in Perl, so change your `runscript` file according to this way:

```
perl get_1000g_r2_prevcf_snplist_e.pl 11:9554976-9657232 EUR ENSG00000133789.txt
perl get_1000g_r2_prevcf_snplist_e.pl 11:70272382-70444560 EUR ENSG00000131626.txt
perl get_1000g_r2_prevcf_snplist_e.pl 11:94324686-94541163 EUR ENSG00000020922.txt
...
```

Comment: The file may well be a command (i.e. executable).